# how to obtain the position from the callback function function(result)

Tags: javascript, here-api

i can not obtain the Route between two markers
any help ?

```
var geocodingParams = { searchText:'street abc'};
```

// Define a callback function to process the geocoding response:

```
var onResult = function(result) {

  var locations = result.Response.View[0].Result,
    position,
    marker;

  // Add a marker for each location found
  for (i = 0;  i < locations.length; i++) {
  position = {
    lat: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,
    lng: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
  };
  marker = new H.map.Marker(position);
  map.addObject(position);

  } 

 }
```

// Get an instance of the geocoding service:

```
var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();

geocoder.geocode(geocodingParams, onResult, onError)
```

//Routing

```
function calculateRouteFromAtoB(platform) { 

  var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
    routeRequestParams = {
      mode: 'fastest;car',
      representation: 'display',
      routeattributes : 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs',
      maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
      language: 'de-DE',
      alternatives : '3',
      waypoint0: 'position of the marker1' ,  
      waypoint1:  'position of the marker2'

    };
  router.calculateRoute(routeRequestParams,onSuccess,onError );

}
```

im trying to define waypoint0 and waypoint1 in the function calculateRouteFromAtoB() , any idee ?

Comment: Could you pass the map , calculateRouteFromAtoB(platform, map) and then you can access the marker points.

Comment: can you more explain!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the objects in your map and see if they are instanceOf H.map.Marker. Basically they would be the markers you have created on the map. If there are no other objects other than markers you have created then you can directly work on those objects.

length = map.getObjects().length //gives the number of markers

assuming you have just two markers (which would go to waypoint0 and 1 respectively), you can write your function as below. Hope this helps!

```
function calculateRouteFromAtoB(platform) { 
  point1 = map.screenToGeo(map.getObjects()[0].getPosition().lat, map.getObjects()[0].getPosition().lng);
  point2 = map.screenToGeo(map.getObjects()[1].getPosition().lat, map.getObjects()[1].getPosition().lng);
  var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
    routeRequestParams = {
      mode: 'fastest;car',
      representation: 'display',
      routeattributes : 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs',
      maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
      language: 'de-DE',
      alternatives : '3',
      waypoint0: point1.lat+','+point1.lng ,  
      waypoint1:  point2.lat+','+point2.lng

    };
  router.calculateRoute(routeRequestParams,onSuccess,onError );

}
```

Comment: the function 'calculateRouteFromAtoB' was called before the function where the markers are initialized.
I do not understand why  --Thanks for your help